Consuming Azure Service Bus message by only one consumer in Topic-Subscriber topology
I have three separate applications. (1) Legal-Processor (2) Purchase-Order-processor (3) Document-Uploader. Each application has multiple instances running. The "Document-Uploader" publishes a message whenever a document is uploaded. The Legal-Processor should consume the message only if the document is "legal". If the document is "Purchase-order" related, then the "Purchase-Order-processor" must consume the message.
What do I need to configure the topic/subscription in Azure service bus so that only one instance of either  "Legal-Processor" or  "Purchase-Order-processor" must process the message? Basically, I want both of them to receive the message, and depending on some filter/property, they can consume the message. The problem I am having is that both these applications have ten instances running.

Does your  "Document-Uploader" processor know what kind of document it has uploaded? It can then set a property on the message indicating the message type (legal or purchase order).

The publisher needs to set a property on which Service bus can filter to the respective subscription. Then the subscribers will receive only the messages intended for them. You can refer to this link on how to set your topics and subscriptions up to filter on a property
https://medium.com/@anupamchand/subscription-filtering-in-azure-service-bus-9dfe50bbd88e And you can refer to this https://pmichaels.net/2022/02/26/custom-and-system-properties-in-azure-service-bus-messages-using-azure-messaging-servicebus/ on how to set the properties. But it depends on the language the publishers are using.

Yes. I solved it by creating two separate subscribers - (1) Legal-Subscriber (2) Purchase-order-Subscriber. Thank you.

@user1250720 It's great to hear that you were able to resolve your issue. Could you please document your solution in an answer? It would provide clarity for those encountering similar technical challenges within the community.

One should use filter in the Topic's Subscription to handle this. The legal processor application will need to use the subscription that has the filter condition like 'DocType=Legal'.  See the doc here and the code sample here
